# Am I using the wrong argument in fopen?

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, string

I am appending json values to an external file. The form data is captured with ajax and post variables. I have a small script that explodes the json data string and attempts to implode the file back together with the post variables in the middle (or actually at the end).

```
<?php

$json_file = "data.json";
$json_data = $_POST["newUpload"]."]}"; 
//something like {"name":"foo","email":"foo@bar.com"}

$fh = fopen($json_file, 'r+'); //I think this is the problem???

$data = fread($fh, filesize($json_file));   
$jsonFrags = explode("]}",$data);
$new_data = implode($json_data,$jsonFrags);
fwrite($fh, $new_data);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

This was the easiest thing I could come up with the allow a list of users to grow on a website running off of XAMPP and a Windows machine with VERY limited internet access. Once maybe twice a day.

The whole JSON looks like this:

```
{"uploads": [{"name":"foo","email":"foo@bar.com","imgurl":"http://placehold.it/50x50"}]}
```

I load the file data into `$data` and explode it at the end of the file character string "]}". That way it always appends to the end. But its not explode / implode giving me problems. I can use str_replace and get the same result. After running that PHP script above, I get this in data.json:

```
{"uploads": [{"name":"foo","email":"foo@bar.com","imgurl":"http://placehold.it/50x50"}]}{"uploads": [{"name":"bar","email":"bar@foo.com","imgurl":"http://placehold.it/100x100"}]}
```

I have been able to change the argument for fopen to get different results, none of which are the results I was hoping for. Any ideas?

Comment: There are much better ways of storing data -- if MySQL is too big and heavy, try SQLite. Messing around with JSON like this will just give you a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't defined the variable `$json` at all.  for all PHP knows, `$json` is null.  your code is trying to open a file (for reading), but the file is null!